# Regular expression used with scanf() or sscanf()

Tags: c, regex, scanf

I am aware that regular expressions can't be used in these functions. But still there are few expression that can be used to effectively parse the expression.

Some expression I found in my searches are, `*, [], ^` etc but could not get any documented help on the same. Few examples are as follows,

```
scanf("%*[ ]%ns%*[ ]\n",str); or
enter code here
MAIN_STRING = "bhupesh, bhupesh.pant@gmail.com,";
std::string str1;
std::string str2;
sscanf(MAIN_STRING.c_str(), "%[^,] %[^,]", str1.c_str(), str2.c_str());
```

output:-

```
str1 = bhupesh
str2 = bhupesh.pant@gmail.com
```

I wanted to know all the possible symbols and regular expression kind of symbols that can be used in such situations.
I am writing a simple parser so just wondering if I can make use of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to work on your search skills. One tip is to search for "man X" where X is a standard library function.

This will bring you [the manual pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) from Linux (among other platforms) which are typically quite good.

For instance the linked page says this about `[`:

> Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified set of accepted characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters in the string, plus a terminating null byte. The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed. The string is to be made up of characters in (or not in) a particular set; the set is defined by the characters between the open bracket [ character and a close bracket ] character. The set excludes those characters if the first character after the open bracket is a circumflex (^). To include a close bracket in the set, make it the first character after the open bracket or the circumflex; any other position will end the set. The hyphen character - is also special; when placed between two other characters, it adds all intervening characters to the set. To include a hyphen, make it the last character before the final close bracket. For instance, [^]0-9-] means the set "everything except close bracket, zero through nine, and hyphen". The string ends with the appearance of a character not in the (or, with a circumflex, in) set or when the field width runs out.

Comment: the documentation was quite a much but still I am not able to try and make my own conversion specification. I will go through it few more time and see if I am able to understand. Thanks a lot unwind..

Answer (score 3):

The documentation can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). Excerpt:

> [characters]  Scanset Any number of the characters specified between
>   the brackets. A dash (-) that is not the first character may produce
>   non-portable behavior in some library implementations.
>
> [^characters] Negated scanset Any number of characters none of them
>   specified as characters between the brackets.
>
> *  An optional starting asterisk indicates that the data is to be read from the stream but ignored (i.e. it is not stored in the location
>   pointed by an argument).

There is not much more than that.

For more expresiveness, you need to lookup [Lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser) and [Bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison)

Comment: Hi, I followed the link and this is quite a much for my simple test prog for which I needed . But I am really thankful for you that you showed me something I never knew. Now I think someday I should go through it and set it all up, because its really nice to know thing..

Answer (score 1):

They're not regular expressions, they match using a VERY simple algorithm.

Use "Flex" and "Bison" (they go hand in hand) to do this well.

To learn about finite state automata and regex see "Tobias"'s book (IIRC) called "An introduction to compiler design" the first section is the lexing stage, regex for finding tokens.

**Addendum**

Flex (and Bison) are really REALLY easy, even parsing CSV files is nicer with them, they are superb tools and really unappreciated.